# Background-image height 100%

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm looking for a solution of my problem.

I am using twitter bootstrap for a mobile site and this is my outcome on mobile view:

[image]

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span4">
        <div class="visible-phone" style="background-image: url('http://upload.tapcrowd.com/upload/catalogimages/719/catalogimagecardealer@2x.png');></div>
        <p class="metadataTitle metacell">
        <span style="display: inline-block" class="ellipsis">Car Dealers</span>
        <span style="table-row"></span></p>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

The css of the div where my image is in:

```
background-size:contain;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
width: 100%; 
height: 300px;"
```

But as you can see there is a margin between the image and the content below, does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: Make sure you set `Margin: 0px` in the CSS on both pieces of content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `margin:0; padding:0;` to both the image and the content below. This will remove any margin. Since HTML adds a margin by default, you need to explicitly tell HTML to remove a margin.

Answer (score 5):

> background-size:contain;

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size:

> *"contain: This keyword specifies that the background image should be scaled to be as large as possible while ensuring both its dimensions are less than or equal to the corresponding dimensions of the background positioning area."*

So your image has been scaled so that it fits into the element completely - you seem to want to use `cover` instead:

> *"cover: This keyword specifies that the background image should be scaled to be as small as possible while ensuring both its dimensions are greater than or equal to the corresponding dimensions of the background positioning area."*